# C++ delete[] operator confusion

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I am studying pointers atm. and I got confused with delete[] operator.
Here is an example:

```
int* a = new int[12];

for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
    a[i]=123;

delete[] a;

for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
  cout <<a[i]<<" ";
```

If I got it correctly, `delete[]` operator should destory all objects in an array.
But my output is this:

```
10621288 10617028 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123
```

Only first two elements are destroyed.
Have I made something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done wrong is trying to access the contents of `a` after it has been deleted. This invokes undefined behavior (UB), which means "anything goes". **You must never do that, it is a crash-worthy bug in the code.**

The results you see are simply one particular specialization of "anything". Running this program on another system, or using a different compiler, or using the same compiler with different settings, is likely to end up doing something else.

Comment: @kr4lj: In this case there is nothing to destroy because the array contains integers -- only the memory for the array itself is released. If the array contained objects you would see their destructors being called one by one.

Comment: I did the same, got the first 2 elements zeroed. You cannot physically dleete a memory location :D just makes zero if zero is a null for compiler and releases for later use.

Answer (score 2):

Your code invokes an Undefined Behavior, since you're trying to get access to already released memory. Anything could happen.

Answer (score 2):

**You just got lucky** that the output still shows as if the data actually exists. But your understanding is correct. You have to perform a delete[] a.

**On any other day you would have seen a crash.** Invalid pointer deferencing exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior. Destroying memory is not the same as destroying, say, a book or a vase: the memory does not disappear, and some of its content may remain untouched.

However, accessing such memory makes your program illegal: your program no longer owns that chunk of memory, it belongs to some other code or to another part of your program. Any part of that memory can be overwritten at any time. Moreover, your program can crash when you access such memory.